# Получение значения из таблицы JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

как получить значение `id` из jdbc?
у меня есть класс `User` с такими полями и аннотациями:

```
@IdInformation("id")
private Long id;

@ColumnName("name")
private String name;

@ColumnName("password")
private String password;

@ColumnName("email")
private String email;
```

в классе по сути мы ничего не делаем с полем `id`. Значения уже присуждаются в БД. Не могу понять как правильно и корректно вытащить это значение оттуда.

Comment: а что за аннотация @IdInformation? гугл издевается и не дает ответа.

Comment: а гугл вам и не даст ответ :)
@IdInformation - это просто название, которое я присвоила анотации

Comment: вы используете  чистый jdbc или ORM?

Comment: а зачем вам анотации @ColumnName при использовании JDBC? это как бы фитча для орм...

Comment: Попробуйте уточнить с чем именно возникли проблемы. Пока подходит вопрос: написать запрос и прочитать id. Если требуется какая-то автоматизация, то распишите подробнее что происходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень понимаю в чем суть вопроса, а почему нельзя написать так:

```
Statement stmt;
String query = "select id, name, password, email from User";

stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
while (rs.next()) {
    String id = rs.getString("id");
}
```

В чем собственно говоря проблема то?

Comment: проблема в том, что я не знала как правильно вытащить id из таблицы и можно ли его значение передать переменной. чуть позже обязательно попробую ваш вариант

Answer (score 0):

Смущают аннотации, но если речь всё таки о голом JDBC, то получить сгенерированный id можно как минимум двумя способами:

Явный SQL запрос к базе данных после внесения записи

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Либо так

```
int id = statement.executeUpdate(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```